# Image is not attaching to SMS

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mms, android-mms

I am trying to share image and text via SMS. I am adding the image Uri but Image is not attached with SMS. What is wrong with my code please tell me Advance Thanks.

```
`Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            share.setType("image/png");
            share.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
            Uri uri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",file);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(share);
```

Comment: `Uri.fromFile()` results in a `Uri` that has a `file` scheme. That has been banned (for the most part) since Android 7.0. Use `FileProvider` to serve up your content, and use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to populate your `EXTRA_STREAM` extra. Also, use a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard. And, bear in mind that there is no requirement for any SMS client to support `ACTION_VIEW` with an otherwise-empty `sms:` `Uri`.

Comment: Here is [the documentation for sending an SMS via an `Intent`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#SendMessage).

Comment: This does not solve my problem

Comment: You might consider editing your question and providing the revised source code, in case we spot problems with your new implementation.

Comment: My image is in sdcard and file provider does not support removable storage.

Comment: Use the Storage Access Framework to allow the user to choose your content, then use the `Uri` that you get back in your `EXTRA_STREAM` value. Bear in mind that you have limited access to removable storage on Android 4.4+, and you have almost no access to removable storage on Android 10+.

Comment: I edit the code here is the thing but result is same Image is not attaching to sms.